# MVC JQuery dynamic table row remove makes my model null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a strange issue with removing a table row. I basically have a table listing out items from my model and I want to do a bulk edit. I also want to allow for a table row to be remove (before a submit). All is well except when I delete the very first row in the table, when I post the form to my controller the collection is null. If I delete any other row the collection perfectly reflects the table. Just the first row is nulling out the model being posted.

Here is some javascript

```
        $("#tableItems").delegate('a.delete', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr.tableItem).append();
    });
```

here is my controller

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [NoCacheAttribute]
    public JsonResult SaveItems(Modelmodel)
    {
        //model.collection is null here if I remove the first row from table
        return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
    }
```

I have a editortemplate that repeats the rows like so:

```
<tr class="tableItem">
<td style='width:100%;border-right:solid 1px black;border-top:solid 1px black;background-color:@Model.BackgroundColor;'>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Notes, new { style="width:100%"})</td>
<td style='border-top:solid 1px black;background-color:@Model.BackgroundColor;'><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
```

and in my main view I have some html that looks like this:

```
<table id="tableItems">
    <trbody>
    <tr>
    <td style=' text-align:right;background-color:#F1F1F1;' colspan='6'>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style='background-color:#F1F1F1;' colspan='6'><strong>Name: </strong>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td style='border-right:solid 1px black;border-top:solid 1px black;background-color:#C0C0C0;'><strong>Notes</strong></td>
            <td style='border-top:solid 1px black;background-color:#C0C0C0;'><strong>Actions</strong></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>

            <td colspan="6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.collection)
        </tbody>
        </trbody>
        </table>
```

any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: First of all there is missing `'` sign in row `$(this).closest('tr.tableItem).append();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when binding to a collection, the razorviewengine uses indicies to denote each record.  The way the model binder works with arrays that are passed in is to start at 1 and work through until it hits a gap in the index.

it can't deal with gaps.  so having the first index missing means it won't attempt to bind the rest.

here is a post from phill haack about it along with the solution:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx